# Error: The getter 'queryParameters' isn't defined for the class 'GoRouterState'

Tags: flutter, xcode

Hi I've been testing my app with Xcode and had no issues, but after recently updating flutter, I'm getting this error and have tried all the solutions on the forums but nothing seems to work yet:

Error (Xcode): lib/flutter_flow/nav/nav.dart:383:14: Error: The getter 'queryParameters'
isn't defined for the class 'GoRouterState'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Code Block where it is failing:

```
extension _GoRouterStateExtensions on GoRouterState {
  Map<String, dynamic> get extraMap =>
      extra != null ? extra as Map<String, dynamic> : {};
  Map<String, dynamic> get allParams => <String, dynamic>{}
    ..addAll(pathParameters)
    ..addAll(queryParameters)
    ..addAll(extraMap);
  TransitionInfo get transitionInfo => extraMap.containsKey(kTransitionInfoKey)
      ? extraMap[kTransitionInfoKey] as TransitionInfo
      : TransitionInfo.appDefault();
}

class FFParameters {
  FFParameters(this.state, [this.asyncParams = const {}]);

  final GoRouterState state;
  final Map<String, Future<dynamic> Function(String)> asyncParams;

  Map<String, dynamic> futureParamValues = {};
```

When I run flutter pub get:

```
Resolving dependencies... (1.4s)
  _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 (65.0.0 available)
  analyzer 5.13.0 (6.3.0 available)
  flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface 3.2.0 (5.0.0 available)
  flutter_facebook_auth_web 3.2.0 (5.0.0 available)
  google_api_headers 1.6.0 (3.1.0 available)
  google_fonts 4.0.4 (6.1.0 available)
  http 0.13.6 (1.1.1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  package_info_plus 4.2.0 (5.0.1 available)
  pigeon 11.0.1 (14.0.0 available)
  shared_preferences_ios 2.1.1 (discontinued replaced by shared_preferences_foundation)
  uuid 3.0.7 (4.2.1 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
Got dependencies!
1 package is discontinued.
13 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

I've tried to run flutter pub outdated, and get the following:

```
Showing outdated packages.
indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name       Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies:
google_fonts       *4.0.4   *4.0.4      *4.0.4      6.1.0   
package_info_plus  *4.2.0   *4.2.0      *4.2.0      5.0.1   

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.
```

Any guidance on troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Brendan

Comment: Could you please share a code sample of what is failing?

Comment: I added the code block to my question. Apologies in advance if this isn't sufficient. I'm building this in flutterflow, I'm not technical. Please let me know if there's more you'd like to see.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe after upgrading flutter and pub get go_router got upgraded too (which seems more likely because flutter pub outdated didn't mention go_router as stale) and now after version 10.0.0 you need to use uri instead of `queryParameters` as a getter, more info at [Migrating to 10.0.0](https://flutter.dev/go/go-router-v10-breaking-changes)

---

You can change your extension to use the getter from uri which has queryParameters (this is the new implementation)

```
extension _GoRouterStateExtensions on GoRouterState {
  Map<String, dynamic> get extraMap => extra != null ? extra as Map<String, dynamic> : {};

  Map<String, dynamic> get allParams => <String, dynamic>{
     ...pathParameters,
     ...uri.queryParameters,
     ...extraMap
  };
  TransitionInfo get transitionInfo => extraMap.containsKey(kTransitionInfoKey)
      ? extraMap[kTransitionInfoKey] as TransitionInfo
      : TransitionInfo.appDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your note @EdwynZN, I'm using flutterflow's nocode/lowcode builder so I'm apprehensive to edit the source code myself as I'm not technical and I assumed the platform would generate the correct packages/dependencies for me. I tried dart fix --apply but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Try changing allParams to use uri.queryParameters instead of just parameters, check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to downgrade to prior version of flutter. Thanks @EdwynZN for the help.